# Why does Louis-Ferdinand Céline refer to Proust as "Prout-Proust"?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, orthographe, histoire, littérature

In *Bagatelles pour un massacre*, Céline refers to Proust as "***Prout***-***Proust***" several times, for example:

"M. Giradoux, c'est un fait bien pertinent, fignolise quand il s'y donne, tout aussi bien que Prout-Proust."

Why does he do that, despite the fact that Proust himself was a Jew? Does "***Prout***-***Proust***" sound funny in French?

Comment: http://parolesdesjours.free.fr/celineetproust.pdf

Comment: Merci pour le lien !

Answer (score 6):

The insulting part comes from "prout" being the standard onomatopoeia in french for a fart.

Comment: "Prout-prout" is also an adjective synonym with "guindé", "pompeux", "snob" without much reference to farts. I think it may be the case here...

Comment: @LaurentS. Your comment has the merits to be an answer in itself. Given the context, it's a better explanation than what Circeus' answer.

Comment: thanks @OlivierGrégoire you're right, I turned it into an answer now that I had more time to elaborate :-)

Comment: @LaurentS. I've heard "prout-prout" before (in a Kavanaugh show: "Je suis un VIP, moi, very important prout-prout"), but I'm from Quebec, so I never thought it was a specific usage.

Comment: C'est un peu comme le [_pêteux de broue_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%A9teux_de_broue) finalement. Pour recréer comme un équivalent d'emploi mais vieillot, peut-être un truc avec la préposition _à_ et le nom, qui serait compris de la même manière ailleurs aussi, sauf pour le choix de prép. : _le pêteux à Proust_. Bof.

Answer (score 6):

Prout-Proust est selon moi utilisé ici comme référence à l'adjectif "prout-prout", auquel je n'arrive pas à trouver une référence "officielle" (edit: [mentionné comme synonyme de "guindé" par Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/guinde)), mais celle du [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prout-prout) correspond à l'usage:

1. (Familier) (Péjoratif) Se dit de quelqu’un qui est trop distingué, précieux, qui fait beaucoup de manières.
   *Très prout-prout la dame. La lèvre pincée, le regard jaugeur, la mine inquisitrice, le maintien guindé, le geste maniéré, tout cela contribue à bâtir cet être de bois et de pierre.* — (Eva Liebermann, La Lyre de la Grande Souveraine, page 154, 2012)
2. Qui dénote des manières précieuses, ou qui en est le lieu.

- *Faut m’tutoyer, ma p’tite Mack, sinon ça fait trop prout prout pour les lieux !* » — (Astrid Plouzennec, Ma voix, page 32, 2010, Éditions Publibook)
- *A New York City, tous les restos un peu prout-prout portent des noms de prénoms français.* — (Le Petit Futé, Mulhouse 2013, page 14, Collectif, 2012)

J'avoue ne pas être connaisseur en literature, mais après de rapides recherches je crois comprendre que Céline n'était pas exactement un fan de Proust. Ce jeu de mots est donc vraisemblablement employé par Céline pour signifier de manière humoristique et concise tout le bien qu'il pense de Proust.

Personnellement je n'ai pas d'avis sur le fond, mais sur la forme, je trouve ça plutôt drôle et bien trouvé :-)

EDIT: I didn't realize the question was asked in English, so here's an English summary of my answer.

"Prout-prout" is an adjective qualifying a person or a thing being "stilted" or "prim" (hope these are valid English adjectives... never used it myself). With my limited English vocabulary, the closest I can think of would be "pedantic".

I think this word from Céline is a sarcastic yet humoristic way for him to mention his feelings about Proust or Proust's style

Comment: I never checked, but I kinda assumed that "prout-prout" was somehow a reference to "péter plus haut que son cul".